# iOS download whole HTML page and exhibit from local on webView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Thanks to [thelaws](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329801/thelaws) I've fixed the exhibiting problem in the device. But I still need to fix the images issue. Gotta download them along with the HTML and exhibit as well, any hints?

**EDIT:**

**-FIXED** Actually I am using this code, i got from [Anne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388037/anne) in another thread. It works (not showing images nor anything else than html) on iOS Simulator but fails to exhibit anything (not even console errors) when i try to run in my device, what's the problem?

```
// Determile cache file path
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", path, @"index.html"];   

// Download and write to file
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.nl"];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

// Load file in UIWebView
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

Fixed the path to:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't write to the bundle on a Device, although it works on the simulator.

Please see [Technical Q&A QA1662](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1662/_index.html) for more details straight from Apple